# How do I assert equal two pydantic models with mock attributes in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pydantic, pytest-mock

lets say I have the following assert statement with the pydantic models:

```
assert my_schedule == [
    Class.construct(
        student_id=student1.student1.id,
        property=Property.A,
        est_time=mock.ANY,
    ),
    Class.construct(
        student_id=student1.student1.id,
        property=Property.B,
        est_time=mock.ANY,
    )
]
```

Now all other attributes except est_time are equal. i,e:

```
my_schedule = [
    Class(
        student_id=student1.id,
        property=Property.A,
        est_time=datetime(2020,1,3),
    ),
    Class(
        student_id=student1.id,
        property=Property.B,
        est_time=datetime(2020,1,4),
    )
]
```

But the above assertion fails because the objects returned with mock.ANY in est_time attribute do not have the same reference id nor its attributes from the actual result.

I want to mock est_time, because it is not part of the test scope as well it being difficult / cumbersome to calculate each time. (the calculation is based on the current time.)

This is what I did eventually, but I am looking for a "cleaner / more pythonic way" to achieve the same result:

```
expected_list = [
    Class.construct(
        student_id=student1.student1.id,
        property=Property.A,
        est_time=mock.ANY,
    ),
    Class.construct(
        student_id=student1.student1.id,
        property=Property.B,
        est_time=mock.ANY,
    )
]

for result, expected in zip(my_schedules, expected_list):
    assert result.dict() == expected.dict()
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing it correctly by using `mock.ANY` since `mock.ANY == datetime(2020,1,3)` is always true. Can you provide a [mcve]? I can't reproduce it with custom pydantic models.

Comment: You are correct, It must have been a typo on my part. Trying it now again works fine. Should you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'd rather close as not reproducible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

you can overide the method **eq** in Class

```
 def __eq__(self, other):
        if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
            return self.dict() == other.dict()
        return NotImplemented
```

and then in the test the assert would be `assert expected_list == my_schedule`

Answer (score 1):

Hello from the future.

As of (at least) pydantic 1.10.1 you can directly compare pydantic models with the equality operator;

```
import pydantic

class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str
    c: float

t1 = Test(a=1, b='1', c=1.0)
t2 = Test(a=1, b='1', c=1.0)
t3 = Test(a=2, b='2', c=2.0)
print(t1 == t2)
# True
print(t1 == t3)
# False
```